# Why Testing Controller not working with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) & @WebMvcTest annotation?

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting the below error when I try to run my controller test. Please can you let me know what I am missing? Why should I add the @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest ?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

```
@Controller 
public class BasketController {

@Autowired
private BasketService basketService;


@GetMapping(value="/baskets/{basketId}")
public ResponseEntity<BasketDto> getBasket(@PathVariable("basketId") UUID basketId){
    Basket basket = basketService.getBasket(basketId);
    BasketDto dto = toBasketDto(basket);
    ResponseEntity response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(dto);
    return response;
}


private BasketDto toBasketDto(Basket basket){
    BasketDto dto = new BasketDto(basket.getBasketId(), basket.getItems());
    return dto;
}
```

}

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BasketController.class)
public class BasketControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BasketService basketService;


    @Test
    public void testGetItemsInBasketSuccessfully() throws Exception {
        UUID basketId = UUID.randomUUID();
        String URI = "/api/baskets/" + basketId;
        Basket mockBasket = new Basket(basketId);

        Mockito.when(basketService.getBasket(basketId)).thenReturn(mockBasket);

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(URI).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        String actualJson = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(actualJson);

    }
}
```

Comment: Generally because you aren't following the recommended packaging and put your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class somewhere in a nested package instead of the top-level one.

Comment: I dont have springbootapplication annotation anywhere. If I dont have a class with this annotation and still need to test my controller what should I do?

Comment: You need to create a configuration. You state you are using Spring Boot but if you don't have an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class you aren't really using Spring Boot. I would suggest adding such a class to the top-level package you have.

Comment: I thought I will be able to test the controller without creating a springbootapplication? So for testing my controller do I need a class with the SpringBootApplication annotation?

Comment: Yes or at least a class with the mentioned specific configuration. What makes you think that you can use a spring boot specific test annotation without the proper infrastructure I wonder?